# AQGridView - DidSelectItemAtIndex Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, aqgridview

I've been having some trouble with this for some time now but the DidSelectItemAtIndex method works the first time but when I pop back the view controller and the AQGridView reappears the DidSelectItemAtIndex doesn't work anymore. I've added touchBegan in the main viewcontroller where the grid exists and it didn't get caught with the exception of the first time, however I added the touchBegan to the Cell class I created and it catches the touch everytime.

Correction, it doesn't allow you to select the same cell back to back.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem is? Also, I can post code, just let me know what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just had to call

deselectItemAtIndex right after I selected it.